# Convert Fortran array to C array (column-major to row-major)

Tags: matlab

Given an arbitrarily-shaped `x`, how to make it so that `o = x(idx)` indexes per C as opposed to Fortran? That is, traverses the unraveled array row-major, not column-major.

A motivation is that, certain conditional should result in a sorted array when traversed row-major: `isequal(x(x > 0), sort(x))`

#### Clarification

*"*`o = x(idx)` *indexes per C"* means matching Python NumPy's `o = x[idx]`. Let `xre = reorder(x)`, left = MATLAB, right = Python:

- `xre(:)` == `x.flatten()`
- `xre(i1:i2, i3:i4, i5:i6)` == `x[j1:j2, j3:j4, j5:j6]`; `j = i - 1`

[Try live](https://replit.com/@OverLordGoldDra/MealyRunnyPaintprogram#main.py)

[Definitions](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/805-4940/z40009104429/index.html) -- "row-major" generalizes to "outer-first", and "column-major" to "inner-first", referring to traversal of the flattened array, which `permute` alone does *not* achieve (nor could it in theory, as shapes can't change).

#### Demo

MATLAB:

```matlab
s = @(x, i0, i1, i2)reshape(x(i0, i1, i2), 1, []);

xF = reshape(1:2*3*4, [2 3 4]);
{s(xF, 1:2, 1, 1), s(xF, 1, 1:2, 1), s(xF, 1, 1, 1:2)}
```

```matlab
{[1 2]}    {[1 3]}    {[1 7]}
```

Python:

```py
import numpy as np
xC = np.arange(1, 2*3*4+1).reshape(2, 3, 4)
print(xC[0:2, 0, 0], xC[0, 0:2, 0], xC[0, 0, 0:2])
```

```py
[ 1 13] [1 5] [1 2]
```

MATLAB `permute`:

```matlab
xp = permute(xF, [3 2 1]);
{s(xp, 1:2, 1, 1), s(xp, 1, 1:2, 1), s(xp, 1, 1, 1:2)}
```

```matlab
{[1 7]}    {[1 3]}    {[1 2]}
```

`permute` alone doesn't achieve what's asked. Even if it somehow did, it's guaranteed out-of-bounds depending on `i0, i1, i2`.

Comment: I don't follow the confusions about my question. "how to make it so that `o = x(idx)` indexes per C" seems unambiguous to me; NumPy is row-major, and my answer demonstrates satisfying the quoted requirement. I've added detail, if it's still unclear, please explain what "indexes per C" or "row-major" means to you.

Answer (score 1):

Per your request, here is what column-major vs row-major order means to me. MATLAB and Fortran use column-major memory order for arrays. C/C++ uses row-major memory order for arrays. E.g., in MATLAB:

Create a 2x3x4 3D array with the numbers 1 through 24 arranged sequentially in memory order:

```
>> x = reshape(1:24,2,3,4)
x(:,:,1) =
     1     3     5
     2     4     6
x(:,:,2) =
     7     9    11
     8    10    12
x(:,:,3) =
    13    15    17
    14    16    18
x(:,:,4) =
    19    21    23
    20    22    24
```

Demonstrating the memory order:

```
>> x(:)
ans =
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
     7
     8
     9
    10
    11
    12
    13
    14
    15
    16
    17
    18
    19
    20
    21
    22
    23
    24
```

Now pass that into a C-mex routine for demonstration:

The mex code (bare bones no argument checking):

```
// File array3d_naive.c

/* Includes ----------------------------------------------------------- */

#include "mex.h"
#include <string.h> // for memcpy( )

/* Gateway ------------------------------------------------------------ */

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // A 3D array of shape 2x3x4
    double array[2][3][4];
    void *ptarget, *psource;
    psource = mxGetData(prhs[0]);
    ptarget = array;
    // Copy the data into the array in MATLAB memory order
    memcpy(ptarget,psource,2*3*4*sizeof(double));
    // Print out the (2,2,2) element, [1][1][1] in C
    mexPrintf("element [1][1][1] = %f\n",array[1][1][1]);
}
```

Compile and run and compare:

```
>> mex array3D_naive.c
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C)'.
MEX completed successfully.
>> x(2,2,2)
ans =
    10
>> array3D_naive(x)
element [1][1][1] = 18.000000
```

Doesn't match, as expected.

Now use permute on the MATLAB side to change the data memory order to row-major by reversing the dimensions:

```
>> y = permute(x,[3,2,1])
y(:,:,1) =
     1     3     5
     7     9    11
    13    15    17
    19    21    23
y(:,:,2) =
     2     4     6
     8    10    12
    14    16    18
    20    22    24
```

y is a 4x3x2 shaped array and the memory ordering of the data has been changed (it is *not* just a reshape). E.g., the new memory order of the data:

```
>> y(:)
ans =
     1
     7
    13
    19
     3
     9
    15
    21
     5
    11
    17
    23
     2
     8
    14
    20
     4
    10
    16
    22
     6
    12
    18
    24
```

Pass that into our C-mex routine:

```
>> array3D_naive(y)
element [1][1][1] = 10.000000
```

Now it matches. The MATLAB permute( ) function changes column-major memory order to row-major memory order (or vice-versa) by reversing the dimensions of arbitrary shaped arrays. On the MATLAB side the shape of the array changes of course because we reversed the dimensions. But the original 2x3x4 shape on the MATLAB side (column-major) matches the desired same shape on the C side 2x3x4 so that you can do the indexing in a similar fashion (with the exception of 1-based vs 0-based), we just had to rearrange the memory using the permute( ) function first. No extra flattening or reshaping necessary.

That is what switching from column-major to row-major (or vice-versa) means to me.  If you don't want to rearrange the memory, then you would typically set up your array in C to be reverse dimensions to make sense, e.g. that would be array[4][3][2] in this case.

I'm not familiar enough with Python and NumPy to make that analogy.

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I cannot understand your C code, but I acknowledge one can interpret "X-major", generally, a number of ways. I don't see this as suggesting my question is ambiguous, though maybe still uneasy to parse. _"indexes per C"_ should, I'd think, interpret as "same set of M indices in C and Mat fetch the same value". "same set of M indices" requires unchanged shape. My "motivation" example should disambiguate further, since only one approach can pass the `isequal`.

Comment: Perhaps it's unclear that under "Clarification", the `x` is a row-major array. Idea being, `x = load('py_arr.mat')`, and we want `x(i0, i1, i2)` to give same value as `x[i0-1, i1-1, i2-1]` in Python. So, modify `x` such that its column-major traversal yields same values as the row-major traversal of the original.

Answer (score 0):

```matlab
xre = permute(reshape(x, flip(size(x))), flip(1:ndims(x)));
```

works. "Row-major" is alternatively "outer-first", and "column-major" is "inner-first", so to convert one N-dimensional tensor to another, we first flatten, then fill in reverse, then flip order of dimensions.

#### Line by line + example

```matlab
xF = reshape(1:2*3*4*5, [2 3 4 5]);

temp = xF(:);  % flatten (already done by `reshape`, can skip)
temp = reshape(temp, flip(size(xF)));     % fill `5` first, then `4`, ...
xC   = permute(temp, flip(1:ndims(xF)));  % shape is `[5 4 3 2]`, need `[2 3 4 5]`
```

Generate NumPy (Python, C order) reference:

```py
import numpy as np
xN = np.arange(1, 2*3*4*5+1).reshape(2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Compare:

```matlab
{xC(1:2,1,1,1), xC(1,1:2,1,1), xC(1,1,1:2,1), xC(1,1,1,1:2)}
%     {[1 61]}    {[1 21]}    {[1 6]}    {[1 2]}
```

```py
(xN[0:2,0,0,0], xN[0,0:2,0,0], xN[0,0,0:2,0], xN[0,0,0,0:2])
# (array([ 1, 61]), array([ 1, 21]), array([1, 6]), array([1, 2]))
```

(I used extra code in MAT to avoid display issues, e.g. `1x1x1x2 double`)

#### C to Fortran

```matlab
xre = reshape(permute(x, flip(1:ndims(x))), size(x));
```

Comment: I think you should skip the flattening and reshaping. I don’t understand what the purpose is of that, but it changes the shape of the matrix. Just permuting the dimensions should be enough to change the order in which data is stored.

Comment: Flattening is skipped, but swapping dimension orders doesn't suffice. `xre(:)` should flatten to and index to same as in Python (except for 1- vs 0-indexing, negatives, etc).

Comment: For example: `x=reshape(1:10,2,5)`. Applying your code yields an array that flattens to `[1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 10]`. But reading `x` row wise you would get `[1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8 10]`. You get that by only permuting the array.

Comment: 2D is the exception, yes (besides the trivial 1D).

Comment: No, it's not an exception. You can trivially extend the 2D case to nD. 2D will not behave differently from 3D or 4D in terms of storage order. Build any small 3D matrix with three different sizes (e.g. a 2x3x4 array), print it out, read it row wise, then apply your code and flatten the array. Do you see the values in the same order?

Comment: A simple permuting is the very first thing I tried. Since `reshape` isn't a no-op, and it gives desired results, how could no-`reshape` still be correct?

Comment: What I do is imagine the process of filling the tensor in both orders. They "hit the wall" at different points - C increments the second-to-last dimension after traversing the length of the last dimension, while Fortran increments the second dimension after traversing the length of the first. Flattening, filling with proper "stop lengths", and then swapping orders is why this works, though I dunno if there's any shortcuts.

Comment: unless I misunderstand your question, `reshape` doesn't give the desired results in 2D, per the example I tried, and does not give the desired result in 3D, as per another example I just tried now. But if it gives you your desired result, then you might want to reword your question to clarify it, because I have misunderstood it.

Comment: Well how do you understand the first paragraph? My answer shows an example that satisfies "make it so that `o = x(idx)` indexes per C as opposed to Fortran" by comparing vs NumPy, then there's also "traverses the unraveled array row-major, not column-major" which I'm unsure how else to interpret. I'll return to this later.

Comment: I am with Cris and also don't understand this post. The MATLAB permute( ) function does exactly what the title of this post asks for, converts column-major to row-major memory order (or vice-versa) for arbitrary shaped arrays. Like an nD "transpose". That is what it is designed to do without any extra flattening or reshaping involved. All you have to do is specify the dimensions in reverse order. Maybe a small pseudo example of 3D input and desired output would help us understand what you really want, explicitly showing the memory order of the input and desired output.